# Passing a Msg case value as a generic to another function that performs a Http.Post?

Tags: elm

I am attempting to do the following:

```
   Submit ->
        ( model, runtime.tryRegister model Response )
```

Where Response is defined as:

```
| Response (Result Http.Error JsonProfile)
```

**However, the following function does not compile:**

```
tryRegister : Form -> (Result Http.Error a -> msg) -> Cmd msg
tryRegister form msg =
    let
        registerUrl =
            "http://localhost:5000/register"

        body =
            encode form |> Http.jsonBody

        request =
            Http.post registerUrl body decoder
    in
        Http.send msg request
```

**Error:**

```
Http.send msg request
```

> The 2nd argument to function `send` is causing a mismatch. - Function
>   `send` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:
>
> ```
> Http.Request a
> ```
>
> But it is:
>
> ```
> Http.Request JsonProfile
> ```

**Here's the Decoder:**

```
decoder : Decoder JsonProfile
decoder =
    Decode.map4 JsonProfile
        (field "Id" Decode.int)
        (field "FirstName" Decode.string)
        (field "LastName" Decode.string)
        (field "Email" Decode.string)
```

The [source code can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/Lambda-Cartel/Nikeza/blob/master/Client/app/Services/Gateway.elm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to keep the `tryRegister` function generic in the sense that you don't want it tied to `JsonProfile`, then you will need to pass in the decoder as a parameter, rather than refer to the top-level function `decoder`, which is typed to `JsonProfile`.

```elm
tryRegister : Form -> Decoder a -> (Result Http.Error a -> msg) -> Cmd msg
tryRegister form decoder msg =
    let
        registerUrl =
            "http://localhost:5000/register"

        body =
            encode form |> Http.jsonBody

        request =
            Http.post registerUrl body decoder
    in
        Http.send msg request
```

You could then pass the top-level `decoder` function in here:

```elm
Submit ->
    ( model, runtime.tryRegister model decoder Response )
```

Comment: Didn't realize that the following worked: tryRegister : Form -> (Result Http.Error JsonProfile -> msg) -> Cmd msg